# return only 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables one contain students name and id 
students

```
StdID | StdName
  1   |  'John'
```

the seconed contain each subject result in a row

stdresults

```
StdID  | SubjectID | SubjectName | Degree
 1     |      1    |   'English' |  90
 1     |      2    |   'Math'    |  86
```

I want the result to be like this

```
StdID | StdName | Subject1Degree | Subject2Degree | Subject ... Degree
  1      'John'         90               86            ....
```

Whatever was the number of subject

Comment: When I make a join the result is in multi rows 
like this
1 john 90
1 john 86
1 john ..
etc..

Comment: Check this https://vitobotta.com/2015/12/10/mysql-dynamic-column-name/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT T1.STDID,
       T1.STDNAME,
       SUM(CASE WHEN (T2.SUBJECTNAME = 'ENGLISH' AND T2.SUBJECTID = 1) THEN 
              T2.DEGREE  ELSE 0 END) AS SUBJECT1DEGREE,
       SUM(CASE WHEN (T2.SUBJECTNAME = 'MATH' AND T2.SUBJECTID = 2) THEN 
             T2.DEGREE ELSE 0 END)AS SUBJECT2DEGREE
FROM STUDENTS T1, STDRESULTS T2
GROUP BY T1.STDID;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a01693/4)